# I installled Linux on my computer's SSD, but I cant boot to the hard drive to start windows

Tags: linux, hard-drive, boot, windows-10, ssd

I have Linux Mint installed on my SSD. I had Windows 10 installed on my hard disk. On BIOS, I go to Linux by changing the boot order to [Disabled] first.
[Disabled] is apparently SATA1 which is the SSD. SATA5 is my hard disk with Windows 10. Whenever I set the boot order to the hard disk, it still loads Linux. How would I fix this? I set the root to '/' and did nothing with '/boot'.

Comment: Do you have a UEFI-based system? If you see an option called 'Compatibility Support Module' or CSM which is set to 'No' in the BIOS, then you are probably using UEFI.

Comment: When did this problem start? 
It is possible when installing linux to a completely different drive that your mbr on windows side still gets altered or destroyed.
Would this be a possibility?

Comment: I'm not sure. When I removed the SSD, the GRUB bootloader still tries to load Linux.

Comment: Did this happen immediately after Linux install or was it working fine earlier when both OSs were present? Did you keep both drives connected when you installed Linux?  If so most likely during installation of Linux, HDD’s SATA Port was first boot priority so the while Linux was installed on SSD, installation setup its boot loader on HDD. Hence it loads it even after removing SSD. Try to add another entry to Linux Bootloader pointing to Windows 10 and see how it works. Or try to use some third party Bootloader apps to set it up.

Comment: I did the above. It worked.